# How to use bc in bash if statement?

Tags: bash, if-statement, bc

I am trying to use bc to compare a value with decimals in my if statement.
I am not sure if I am using bc correctly in my `if statement` because it doesn't seem to work. It always enters the 4th `if statement` "`IF4`". It doesn't seem like the other conditions are being read properly?

```
 #SET INITIAL SPEED
initialspeed() {

wpm=0
echo wpm: $wpm
#CHECKS IF SPEED WAS GIVEN
if [ -z "$wpm" ]
then
        let wpm=0.6
        echo IF1 wpm: $wpm #DEBUG
#CHECK IF SPEED IS VALID
elif [ 'echo "if$($wpm > 0.6)1;if$($wpm<=0.6)0" | bc' = 1 ]
then
        echo IF2 wpm: $wpm #DEBUG
        echo Error speed is less than 100 wpm
        exit 3
elif [ 'echo "if$($wpm < 0.06)1;if$($wpm<=0.06)0" | bc' = 1 ]
then
        echo IF3 wpm: $wpm #DEBUG
        echo Error speed is more than 1000 wpm
exit 3
else
        wpm=$(echo "scale=2;60/$2 | bc")
        echo IF4 wpm: $wpm #DEBUG
fi
}
```

EDIT:
I am actually trying to write a script similar to the "spritz" speed reader. $1 is the file to be read and $2 is the speed that the words will be displayed to the screen. $2 is am optional argument if its not given I set a default speed.

The speed given should be between 100 and 1000 wpm (0.6 and 0.06 before the calculation)

Comment: Use a shell that supports floating-point, like korn shell.  Almost ANY language other than bash supports floating point.

Comment: The `let` keyword is incompatible with float values, it is integer only. Also, the `[ ' command ' = 1 ]` uses single quotes, which are for constants and wont be evaluated. Use `"$()"` around the `bc` evaluation, like `elif [ "$(echo "if$($wpm > 0.6)1;if$($wpm<=0.6)0" | bc)" = 1 ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use process substitution, but you have single quotes instead of backticks.  Text inside of single quotes is just a literal string to Bash. You are looking for backticks:

```
if [ `command` = "result" ]; then  # notice `command` vs 'command'
```

but the preferred, modern syntax is

```
if [ $(command) = "result" ]; then
```

but this is still rather convoluted -- usually, you want something like

```
if command; then
```

where maybe `command` is a slightly more complex thing than you had originally.

In this particular case, I would wrap your logic in a simple Awk script instead.

You are expected to call this with the wpm value; if it is missing, a default of 0.6 is supplied.

```
initialspeed() {
    local wpm
    wpm=${1:-0.6}
    echo "wpm: $wpm" >&2 # notice quoting
    echo "$wpm" | awk '$1 > 0.6 {
            print "Error: speed $1 is less than 100 wpm" >"/dev/stderr"; exit 3 }
        $1 < 0.06 {  # You had < 0.06 vs <= 0.06 but I guess this is what you meant
            print "Error: speed $1 is more than 1000 wpm" >"/dev/stderr"; exit 3 }
        { printf "%2.2f\n", 60/$1 }'
}
```

Your original script apparently has the wrong comparison for the value 0.06.  Looking at it now, I'm guessing you actually want the value to be between 0.06 and 0.6, inclusive; but in any event, this is just a sketch for you to work from.

Comment: Ok thanks. The awk example would be greatly appreciated. I am not familiar with awk at all

Comment: I have updated with an example script, but you don't really explain what you are trying to do, so it is very tentative.

Comment: Thanks for the awk script example. Sorry for the lack of documentation :/

Comment: Updated to read a single parameter and do calculations on that

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe your test into bc with

```
echo "$wpm > 0.06" | bc
```

Testing the result is possible with

```
if [ $(echo "$wpm > 0.06" | bc) -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "You are going to fast"
else
    echo "Slow"
fi
```

Comment: Quote the evaluation to avoid word splitting `if [ "$(echo "$wpm > 0.06" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then`. (according to shellcheck)

Comment: @andiOak You are right that `wpm=2 3 4` will make my solution break. Since `echo "$wpm > 0.06" | bc` will break, your improvement won't help. We need to check `wpm` first. Something like `[[ $wpm =~ ^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]* ]] || echo "wrong format"`

Comment: Indeed. If the input parameter is uncertain/varying, that's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you intention is to return 0 or 1 depending on wpm value you would need something like this

```
echo "if ( $wpm > 0.6 ) 1 else 0" | bc
```

Comment: I am returning 1 or 0 just to determine if wpm is greater than or less than a specific value and then comparing the if statement to the 1 instead of a float